# Не могу подключиться локально к mongodb в docker-контейнере

Tags: mongodb, docker, dockerfile

Dockerfile
`FROM mongo:latest
EXPOSE 27017
CMD ["/usr/bin/mongod"]`

```
docker build -t mongodb .

sudo docker run -p 27017:27017 --name mongodb mongodb
```

Не могу подключиться к БД с локальной машины, хотя контейнер запущен и сервер БД работает.

Но если заменить комманду на

```
CMD ["mongod"]
```

то всё ОК. В чём отличие?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Разница в том, что в [Dockerfile mongo](https://github.com/docker-library/mongo/blob/0a423591d7243256819edc97cef579206d01f6c7/4.0/Dockerfile) определён ENTRYPOINT. Если в Dockerfile определён ENTRYPOINT, то параметры CMD передаются в качестве аргументов в скрипт, определённый в ENTRYPOINT. В зависимости от способа написания параметров ENTRYPOINT и CMD параметры передаются [по-разному](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#understand-how-cmd-and-entrypoint-interact), но суть не меняется - при наличии ENTRYPOINT всё что указано в CMD - это лишь дополнительные параметры, а не полноценная команда запуска приложения в контейнере. Обладая этим знанием, можете попробовать самостоятельно почитать [ENTRYPOINT mongo](https://github.com/docker-library/mongo/blob/0a423591d7243256819edc97cef579206d01f6c7/4.0/docker-entrypoint.sh) и представить, что случится, если ему в качестве параметра передать не `mongod`, а `/usr/bin/mongod`.

Comment: А если я в своём Dockerfile пишу ENTRYPOINT, то он же должен переопределить его в [Dockerfile mongo](https://github.com/docker-library/mongo/blob/0a423591d7243256819edc97cef579206d01f6c7/4.0/Dockerfile) ?

Comment: Да, ваш ENTRYPOINT переопределит родительский.